# Is it possible to install two services for one package using dh_installinit? How?

Tags: deb

`dh_installinit` looks for `debian/$(package).service`, but a package may provide multiple services.

Is it possible for one to bundle multiples `.service` for one package with this method?

Answer (score 9):

You can call `dh_installinit` multiple times with different `--name` parameters to install multiple services:

```
override_dh_installinit:
        dh_installinit --name=service1
        dh_installinit --name=service2
```

(or similar approaches if you're not using short `dh` style). If your source package builds multiple binary packages, you can add `-p` options to limit `dh_installinit`'s action to the appropriate package.

Comment: @ Stephen Kitt How does this work with service files? The man page section for the `--name` option only mentions `.upstart`, `.init` & `.default` file types. --- *Install the init script (and default file) as well as upstart job file using the filename name instead of the default filename, which is the package name. When this
           parameter is used, dh_installinit looks for and installs files named debian/package.name.init, debian/package.name.default and debian/package.name.upstart instead of
           the usual debian/package.init, debian/package.default and debian/package.upstart.*

Comment: @Wimateeka well spotted, the documentation is out of date there. `--name` is handled globally for all `debhelper` commands, by `Debian::Debhelper::Dh_Getopt`, `::Dh_Lib` and `::Buildsystem`; it works for all supported file types. See for example [`cups`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/printing/cups.git/tree/debian/rules) and [`glibc`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-glibc/glibc.git/tree/debian/rules.d/debhelper.mk) which both use `dh_installinit` with a `--name` argument to install systemd services.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from compatibility level 11, `dh_installinit` no longer handles systemd services. Use `dh_installsystemd` instead:

```
override_dh_installsystemd:
    dh_installsystemd --name=service1
    dh_installsystemd --name=service2
```

(The above assumes that you have two service files: `debian/<package-name>.service1.service` and `debian/<package-name>.service2.service`.)

Comment: This is better in newer packages. An important note, though, the `debian/compat` (or dependency in `debian/control`) must be at least 12 otherwise the `override_dh_installsystemd` is ignored.